# Mortarboard badge at 199 rep

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I've just been notified that I have won the bronze mortarboard badge for earning at least 200 reputation in a single day.

Yet the same notification tells me I've earned just 199 reputation today.

How is this possible?

[image: Screenshot illustrating the problem]

Answer (score 5):

Reading the badge description [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard):

> Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.

Also, taking a look at your rep:

[image]

We can see that you already completed the requirements for the badge, that is **earn at least 200 reps in a day**. You earned 205 reps, which is **sufficient condition for getting the badge**. The -6 you got are not related, nor affect the badge condition.

In other words, if you made 400 reps in a day (just, imagine you do) but took -201 in downvotes (which gives a net number of 199) you still made at least 200 reps that day.

I've noticed a similar situation regarding the Rep Capping. I have in past days rep capped (+1 on my counter) by having +200/-1 , even though the net rep number was 199.

Comment: Aha — I thought it was about net reputation gain.

Comment: @gerrit at first I also thought that, but after several days seeing the behavior of my rep cap counter I concluded such thing.